# Uploading test result to HP ALM

Tags: unix, jenkins

I have created test result file at particular Unix Sever as below
TC1,Pass
TC2,Fail
TC3,Pass
........
and so on

**with the help of jenkins jobs**

I have to upload/update test cases result accordingly in HP ALM test lab.
I have two challenges
1. Transfer this test result file from Unix Server to Jenkins work space
2. And then tried to load result in HP ALM using HP ALM plugin

In step 2, It ask for testing framework(Junit,NUnit,TestNG), which I have not used any.

Please suggest...

Comment: Any idea how can I Transfer File From Unix to Jenkins (Job's Workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Agiletestware Bumblebee (http://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee.html).
It has Jenkins plugin which can execute tests in HP ALM and/or upload test execution results in various formats into HP ALM